# Как связать два input между собой

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код

```html
<div>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="radio">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="radio">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="number">
  <input type="radio">
</div>
```

Количество div может быть любое. И вот надо, чтобы при выборе check записывалось значение из второго input. 
Допустим в первый инпут выписали 1, во второй 2, в третий 3. И выбрали первый и третий инпут через радио, и после сложили значения этих инпутов. Через id нельзя, тк количество дивов может быть не ограничено

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно было попроще написать, но так будет работать наверняка:

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

var inp   = document.querySelectorAll('.inp');
var check = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
var sum   = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < check.length; i++ ){
  (function(i){
    check[i].addEventListener('change', function bubu(){
      var val = inp[i].value;
      sum = (this.checked) ? (sum + +val) : (sum - val);
      demo.textContent = sum;
    });
  })(i);
}
```

```html
 <div>
   <input class="inp" type="number" value="10">
   <input class="check" type="checkbox">
 </div>

 <div>
   <input class="inp" type="number" value="20">
   <input class="check" type="checkbox">
 </div>

 <div>
   <input class="inp" type="number" value="30">
   <input class="check" type="checkbox">
 </div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

P.s.
• input.value достается в виде строки. Это значит, что `"1" + "2" будет 12`. Чтобы не было такой ошибки, перед переменным ставят дополнительный плюсик - он превращает строку в число. Т.е. `+"1" + +"2" == 3` (плюсик нужен только в случае суммирования)

• Можете поискать про разницу let и var, в частности в циклах (обертка `(function(){...})(i)` следует оттуда. С let она не нужна ).

• Тернарный оператор... (условие) ? (значение при выполнении) : (значение в других случаях)

• Google → `previousElementSibling`, `nextElementSibling`, `Делегирование событий`

• "Через id нельзя..." — Можно, но не нужно))

```
id="test-1"
id="test-2"
id="test-3"
...

var id = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="test"]');
```